# Pear PHP_Beautifier returning no output

Tags: ubuntu, php, pear

I intend to use [PHP_Beautifier](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Beautifier) in a code evaluation tool I'm working on but I can't get it working on `Ubuntu 11.10`. I installed it on my local server trough `pear` php package manager with the following command:

```
sudo pear install --alldeps PHP_Beautifier-0.1.15
```

But when I try to invoke the `php_beautifier` on my application it returns no output, and when I execute `php_beautifier` on the terminal the following message is given:

```
$ php_beautifier -f sample.php -o sample.php
>
Jan 06 19:06:21 php_beautifier [error] Nothing on output!
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: file in /usr/bin/php_beautifier on line 225
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: line in /usr/bin/php_beautifier on line 225
```

Any help on how to get PHP_Beautifier to work on `Ubuntu 11.10`?

Comment: Please provide a code sample which demonstrates how you're invoking this. Also, this probably belongs on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. **It seems `php_beautifier` is not able to use the same file as the input** (-f) **and output** (-o), so I just had to use something like this:

```
$ php_beautifier -f ugly.php -o beautiful.php
```

Or suppress the output argument like this, and catch the output returned:

```
$ php_beautifier -f ugly.php
```

Comment: for using your second option simply prints the formatted php to the console, but does not overwrite the original - just as a comment